# Is there any package in python similar to darch in R?

Tags: python

I want to work in Deep Belief Network using Python. Is there any package available in python similar to darch in R.

Answer (score 2):

A simple google with keyword    gives me:

1. A tutorial about implement DBN from scratch
   http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/DBN.html
2. A python package about the DBN
   https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network
3. Some interesting discussion about the DBN (and little history)
   https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/748
4. SO discussion 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188131/deep-belief-network-with-scikit